# Como hacer cliqueable un elemento canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Como podría hacer '*cliqueable*' si la persona, ingresa un `link` para el `fillText` en ***Canvas***?

*Edito: Sigo investigando y he visto que dices que puedo **asociar un controlador de eventos al lienzo**, luego sacar las **coordenadas del texto** y que si pulsa el texto,  l**o redirecciona**, pero además mi problema es que no me sirve hacerlo para un **TEXTO ESTÁTICO**, entonces que debo hacer?*

Con '*cliqueable*' me refiero que se pueda cliquear si es una `URL`, y te lleve a esa `URL` abriendo otra pestaña.

*Investigando leí esto, pero aun no me queda claro como hacerlo en la practica:*

> Puede detectar clics en el lienzo si agrega un controlador de eventos
>   de clic al elemento canvas y, a continuación, extrae los parámetros de
>   posición del ratón del evento, los convierte en coordenadas locales,
>   comprueba los elementos que hace clic y realiza cualquier acción que
>   sea necesaria.

```js
var h = document.getElementById("go");
h.addEventListener("click",function() {
  
var texto = prompt("Ingresa texto a dibujar");
var context = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = context.getContext("2d");

ctx.font = "20px monospace";
ctx.fillText(texto, 20, 60);
  
ctx.font = "40px monospace";
ctx.fillText("Creando textos..", 70, 30);
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input value="Crear texto" type="button" id="go"/>
  <canvas width="1080" height="720" id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Es posible pero requiere de horas de programación, aunque con librerias como Fabric js puede ser más sencillo.

Answer (score 1):

Hice algunos cambios: hay algunas variables que las he sacado del `h.addEventListener`: el canvas, el contexto del canvas: estas variables son constantes y necesitas declararlas una sola vez.

También he añadido una función para recuperar las coordenadas del ratón:`oMousePos`

**La lógica utilizada**: después de pintar el texto estoy calculando la anchura del texto utilizando el método `measureText` del contexto. Voy a utilizar este valor pata esbozar un rectángulo alrededor del texto. Digo "esbozar" porque el rectángulo no tendrá ni `fill` ni `stroke`.

Después al hacer click en el canvas `canvas.addEventListener("click",...` si el ratón se encuentra encima del rectángulo el programa hace algo. En este caso aparece un `alert` pero tu puedes hacer lo que quieras: por ejemplo redirecionar la página.

Para detectar si el ratón se encuentra encima del rectángulo utilizo el método `isPointInPath` del contexto.

**Observación**: veo que utilizas `var context` para el canvas y `var ctx` para el contexto. Los he dejado así pero habría sido mucho más claro utilizar `var lienzo` o `var canvas` en lugar de `var context`.

Espero que sea útil.

```js
var h = document.getElementById("go");
var context = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = context.getContext("2d");
var anchuraTexto;//la anchura del texto es una variable global
var fontSize = 20;
var dondePongoElTexto = {x:20,y:60};// coordenadas utilizadas para dibujar el texto
var raton = {}// las coordenadas del ratón

h.addEventListener("click",function() {
  
var texto = prompt("Ingresa texto a dibujar");
ctx.font = fontSize+"px monospace";
ctx.fillText(texto, dondePongoElTexto.x, dondePongoElTexto.y);
// calcula la anchura del texto
anchuraTexto = ctx.measureText(texto).width;
/*  
ctx.font = "40px monospace";
ctx.fillText("Creando textos..", 70, 30);*/
  
});

canvas.addEventListener("click",(evt)=>{
  raton = oMousePos(canvas, evt)
  ctx.beginPath();
  // este es un rectángulo alrededor del texto. Por favor observa que no hay stroke
  ctx.rect(dondePongoElTexto.x,(dondePongoElTexto.y -fontSize),anchuraTexto,fontSize*1.2);
  if (ctx.isPointInPath(raton.x, raton.y)) {
    alert("has hecho click\ny ahora puedes hacer lo que quieres")
  }
})


// una finción para recuperar las coordenadas del ratón
function oMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var ClientRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
 return { //objeto
 x: Math.round(evt.clientX - ClientRect.left),
 y: Math.round(evt.clientY - ClientRect.top)
}
}
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<input value="Crear texto" type="button" id="go"/>
<canvas width="500" height="200" id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Acá te comparto un ejemplo que cumple con lo siguiente:**

- Validación de un texto para determinar si es una URL.
- Detección de posición del mouse relativo al canvas.
- Detección de colisión para determinar si el texto agregado fue clickeado
- En caso de que el texto sea una URL se pintara de color azul sino de color negro
- Si el texto es una URL y es clickeado se abrirá dicha url en un nuevo tab del browser.

**Ejemplo online:** https://jsfiddle.net/chenay01/awvs3yxL/68

**HTML**

```
<input value="Crear texto" type="button" id="go" />
<canvas width="1080" height="720" id="canvas"></canvas>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
// Variables
var crearTexto = document.getElementById("go");
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var texto = '';
var textoEsUnaUrl = false;
var coordMouse = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  width: 2,
  height: 2
};
var coordTitulo = {
  x: 70,
  y: 0
};
var coordTexto = {
  x: 20,
  y: 40,
  width: 0,
  height: 20,
};

// Validar si un texto es una url
function validarURL(str) {
  var pattern = new RegExp('^(https?:\\/\\/)?' + // protocol
    '((([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}|' + // domain name
    '((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))' + // OR ip (v4) address
    '(\\:\\d+)?(\\/[-a-z\\d%_.~+]*)*' + // port and path
    '(\\?[;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-]*)?' + // query string
    '(\\#[-a-z\\d_]*)?$', 'i'); // fragment locator
  return !!pattern.test(str);
}

// Obtener la posicion del mouse dentro del canvas
function getMousePos(evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
    y: evt.clientY - rect.top
  };
}

// Detectar colision entre dos elementos (2D)
function detectarColision(rect1, rect2) {
  return rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.width &&
    rect1.x + rect1.width > rect2.x &&
    rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.height &&
    rect1.height + rect1.y > rect2.y
}

// Abrir una url en un nuevo tab del browser
function abrirUrlNuevoTab(url) {
  // Abrir nuevo tab
  var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
  // Cambiar el foco al nuevo tab (punto opcional)
  win.focus();
}

crearTexto.addEventListener("click", function() {

  // Obtener el texto
  texto = prompt("Ingresa texto a dibujar");

  // Validamos si el texto es una url
  textoEsUnaUrl = validarURL(texto);

  // Limpiar el canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // Pintar el titulo
  ctx.font = "40px monospace";
  ctx.textBaseline = "top";
  ctx.fillStyle = "black"
  ctx.fillText("Creando textos..", coordTitulo.x, coordTitulo.y);

  // Pintar el texto
  ctx.font = "20px monospace";
  ctx.textBaseline = "top";
  ctx.fillStyle = textoEsUnaUrl ? "blue" : "black";
  ctx.fillText(texto, coordTexto.x, coordTexto.y);

  //Obtenemos el ancho del texto:
  coordTexto.width = ctx.measureText(texto).width;
});

canvas.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

  // Actualizo las coordenadas del mouse
  coordMouse = {
    ...coordMouse,
    ...getMousePos(e)
  }

  // Si el texto es un link entonces abrimos la url en un nuevo tab
  if (texto && textoEsUnaUrl && detectarColision(coordTexto, coordMouse)) {
    abrirUrlNuevoTab(texto);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Con 'cliqueable' me refiero que se pueda cliquear si es una URL, y te
>   lleve a esa URL abriendo otra pestaña

No es posible lo que pretende al menos no con `canvas`  , recuerde que los elementos que se dibujan no tienen ninguna representación *excepto px y color*

> Puede detectar clics en el lienzo si agrega un controlador de eventos
>   de clic al elemento canvas

*Ya lo está haciendo `clickeable` en su código* al añadir el `addEventListener`

> a continuación, extrae los parámetros de posición del ratón del evento, los convierte en coordenadas locales, comprueba los elementos que hace clic y realiza cualquier acción que sea necesaria.

Es verdad que en el evento  `click` como dato del evento está la posición del evento *mouse*`x` , `y` con esto puede dibujar  donde usted de `click` dentro del `canvas` *tiene muchas utilidades*

**Ejm**

```js
var canvas  = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.addEventListener("click",function(e){
  var texto = prompt("Ingresa texto a dibujar");
  var context = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = context.getContext("2d");

  ctx.font = "20px monospace";
  /* Agregamos el texto en la pos x y del click */
  ctx.fillText(texto, e.x, e.y);

});
```

```html
<canvas width="1080" height="720" id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Como? no te entendí

Comment: @EduardoSebastian Qué no entendió ?

Comment: no me explica nada, ni siquiera como hacerlo como un link

Comment: @EduardoSebastian me olvidé de esa parte , no es posible hacer eso con canvas , actualicé mi respuesta.